# How to run composer as non root user on official docker php image

Tags: php, shell, docker, composer-php

I am using the official php:alpine https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/alpine3.7/fpm/Dockerfile as my base image. My projects are basically composer based project. So I installed composer on it like below.

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- --filename=composer
```

When I install any packages using `composer install` it runs as root as the main php process runs as root. So how can I run main php process as root and composer as another non root user `deploy`?

**Update-1** 
My dockerfile is like below. So as you can see I am not installing composer packages inside dockerfile rather I install those packages on **container** like `docker exec -it php composer install`.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine
..........................
..........................
..........................
RUN  set ex \
  # Install Composer( Requires git )
  && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- --filename=composer \
  ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
  CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I was trying to achieve it like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476155/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-su-user-c-command but in vain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incase anyone wants to achieve the same follow instructions below

I added a `USER` in dockerfile so that composer will be run as user `deploy` in future. But php-fpm needs to be run as root. So I set a setuid bit on the php-fpm binary. And now everything got resolved.

```
RUN chmod u+s /usr/sbin/php-fpm7

USER deploy
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm7","-F"]
```

Comment: be care php-fpm run as the user defined in php-fpm.conf if you run it as root, if you run it as another user like here, it will not be root.